# Updating database with jquery ajax in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, sql-update

There are posts here already for this issue but I still don't get the database to update. Ajax sends me a 200 OK but as said no db update: (the $platform->id is not the issue, foreach is set). Thank you for help!

Jquery

```
$('#button_<?php echo $platform->id; ?>').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var platform_id = <?php echo $platform->id; ?>;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('home/select_job'); ?>",
            data: {id : platform_id},
            success: function(){ alert("success"); },
        });
```

Controller

```
$platform_id = $this->input->post('platform_id');
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
$this->users_model->job_selection($user_id, $platform_id);
```

Model

```
public function job_selection($user_id, $platform_id){
    $this->db->set('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->set('status', 2);
    $this->db->set('select_company', 1);
    $this->db->where('id', $platform_id);
    $this->db->update('companies');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making mistake to getting the `platform_id` it will be `id` because you set the name `id` into your ajax call try this into your controller

```
$platform_id = $_POST['id'];
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
$this->users_model->job_selection($user_id, $platform_id);
```

Try this hope it will solve problem.

Comment: Good catch. I try to always leave field names the same...db, form, variable name, JSON/Array key, etc...changing them around from user_id to id, etc just introduces opportunities to screw up.